# SQL Partition by with conditions - two values in the same column

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table like below. The *event_name* and *slot* columns change in this table.

| stream_id | event_date | event_name | promo_name | slot |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 01012222 | select | banana | A1 |
| 123 | 01012222 | select | banana | A2 |
| 123 | 01012222 | select | banana | A3 |
| 123 | 01012222 | select | banana | A3 |
| 123 | 01012222 | select | banana | A3 |
| 123 | 01012222 | view | banana | A1 |
| 123 | 01012222 | view | banana | A1 |
| 123 | 01012222 | view | banana | A2 |
| 123 | 01012222 | view | banana | A3 |
| 123 | 01012222 | view | banana | A4 |

and i am trying to create a pivot table like below.
If the event_name is 'select' how many rows of stream_id, event_date and promo_name columns are the same, I want to add it as the 'event_name_select_count' column. Like below.

| stream_id | event_date | promo_name | slot | event_name_select_count | event_name_view_count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 01012222 | banana | A1 | 1 | 2 |
| 123 | 01012222 | banana | A2 | 1 | 1 |
| 123 | 01012222 | banana | A3 | 3 | 1 |
| 123 | 01012222 | banana | A4 | 0 | 1 |

I tried to do something with a code like below, but I couldn't succeed. I don't know how to 'partition by' for both two values in a column.

`````
SELECT
    stream_id, event_date, event_name, promo_name, slot, 
COUNT(event_name) OVER (PARTITION BY stream_id,event_date, promo_name, slot) AS event_name_count 
FROM `TABLE````
`````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to *partition-by* a table for pivotting. Instead, consider below.

```sql
-- sample data
WITH sample_table AS (
  -- put your same data here
)
-- pivot query starts here
SELECT * 
  FROM sample_table
 PIVOT (COUNT(1) event_name FOR event_name IN ('select', 'view'));

-- query result
+-----------+------------+------------+------+-------------------+-----------------+
| stream_id | event_date | promo_name | slot | event_name_select | event_name_view |
+-----------+------------+------------+------+-------------------+-----------------+
|       123 |   01012222 | banana     | A1   |                 1 |               2 |
|       123 |   01012222 | banana     | A2   |                 1 |               1 |
|       123 |   01012222 | banana     | A3   |                 3 |               1 |
|       123 |   01012222 | banana     | A4   |                 0 |               1 |
+-----------+------------+------------+------+-------------------+-----------------+
```